# How to find antipatterns in your vim workflow?

Tags: vim, vi

There are a lot resources on [vim antipatterns](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vim%20antipatterns&t=hw&ia=web) and although I am aware of the pitfalls I am certain I don't do everything as efficient as it could be done.

What is the best way track antipatterns / inefficiencies in your vim workflow?